# sqlite predefined database null

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm a beginner in Sqlite, so sorry if I made some stupid mistakes :D

I got a NULL error in my predefined database :

[image: NULL error]

This **error** always happened when I **start my App in the new computer/emulator**, so I think it has something to do with my `onCreate` method. But, the `onCreate` should not needed because I use predefined database.

This is my database class :

```
private static String DATABASE_NAME = "ALGOLICIOUS_DB";
    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static String TABLE_NAME = "msQuiz";
    private static String TABLE_HIGHSCORE = "msHighScore";

    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    String queryCreate, queryUpdate, queryDelete, querySelect, queryInsert;
    Cursor cursor;

    public AlgoliciousDB(Context context) {
        this.context = context; 
        OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context); 
        this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
    }

    public List<String> getQuestion(int chapter) {
        List<String> questionList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String result = "";
        querySelect = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE question_chapter = " + chapter;

        try {
            cursor = this.db.rawQuery(querySelect, null);

            for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
                result += cursor.getString(1) + "%" + cursor.getString(2) + "%" + cursor.getString(3) + "%" + cursor.getString(4) + "%" + cursor.getString(5);
                questionList.add(result);
                result = "";
            }
            return questionList;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public int getHighScore(int chapter) {
        querySelect = "SELECT highscore FROM " + TABLE_HIGHSCORE + " WHERE highscore_id = " + chapter;
        int temp = 0;

        try {
            cursor = this.db.rawQuery(querySelect, null);

            for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
                temp = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
            }
            return temp;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public void Close() {
        db.close();
    }

    class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public OpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks :D

Comment: where is your database stored?

Comment: in the default path (/data/data) :D
Thanks

Comment: when you catch an exception, log it, don't simply return a default value. that should help you pin down the issue

Comment: in onCreate, you are supposed to, like, create tables in your database

Comment: @njzk2 the problem is, i dont have any error/exception...my database file just vanished everytime i change the emulator/computer. Thanks :D

Comment: @njzk2 i use the predefined database...so i shouldnt need to re-create the tables :D

Comment: if you update it, you go in onUpgrade, which drops the table, in which case you'd need to create them again. Also, may be your database copy doesn't work. what do you use to import your DB ?

Comment: and still, please do print something when you catch an exception

Comment: you don't have any errors because your catch clause simply returns null. printStackTrace or something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728

Comment: @YaqubAhmad please use that reference to answer my question, so i can accept that. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is here:
[How to use an existing database with an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application/9109728#9109728)

Copy your database in Assets Folder and use the code provided in above link. Sample sample is also available you can try it.